# Can't send POST request from python CGI. Why?

Tags: python, apache, post, cgi

Here is what I think is supposed to be sent:

```
POST /cgi-bin/testscript.py HTTP 1.1
Host: www.someplace.com
Content-Length: 50
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

bleeple=yes&rjunk=0%21603567240941&dummy=certainly
```

But if I put that out on STDIO, apache complains about an invalid header when I send the POST line. And sure enough, it's not a header, it's the preceding request. So, ok, not a header.

Apparently, apache is constructing that request and sending it FOR me, because if I send a GET, like this...

```
Location: http://www.someplace.com/cgi-bin/testscript.py?foo=bar
```

...then apache (must!?) emit this first...

```
GET /cgi-bin/testscript.py HTTP 1.1
```

...right? So how do I make it construct the following prefix to my headers, instead?

```
POST /cgi-bin/testscript.py HTTP 1.1
```

If I *don't* send the post line, then it doesn't know where the script is, and nothing happens that I can see.

If I remove the POST line and add a Location: header with the full URL, then the surfer's browser goes there, all right, but no POST data is picked up.

I have googled until I am half-blind and can't seem to find an answer as to how to emit a proper POST from a CGI in response to someone invoking that CGI from a form.

Of course, this (GET) works just fine, except it exposes the params in the URL bar of the browser, which I am trying to avoid:

```
Location: http://www.someplace.com/cgi-bin/testscript.py?bleeple=yes&rjunk=0%21603567240941&dummy=certainly
```

I want to do this at the most basic level, depending on nothing but my apache server. I can do it with GET and STDIO. I can send HTTP pages, images, etc. But POST? No.

I must be missing something fundamental -- apparently my google-fu is most weak. Or something. Help?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Why do you need to *emit* a POST in response to someone posting a form? And you seem to be confusing what Apache is receiving (the GET or POST line) with what you send out in response (everything else).

Comment: Not that it's at all relevant, but I wish to emit a POST because there are three possible destinations based upon the original form input; when I take the user to those forms, it is my desire that the parameters passed do not appear in the browser's address bar, as they will if I simply append them as parameters in the Location: header. So user arrives in CGI1, and I wish to then POST to CGI2, or CGI3, or CGI4. The capability of setting a location header with parameters means that the user's browser will arrive with a GET request -- that's what it is. I want it to use POST, not GET.

Comment: Continuing (character limit): I don't think what I'm looking for is in any way unreasonable. It may be impossible -- and if so, that's a surprising hole in the way the web works -- but it's *still* not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining what you're trying to do is completely relevant, as I now understand the question, whereas I didn't before.

As I said in the comment, you're confusing input with output: just putting "POST" at the start of your response doesn't somehow make a post to another URL. You'd need to actually make the post from within your script itself, eg using the `urllib` module from the stdlib or the third-party `requests` library.

But at this point you need to ask yourself why you are using CGI. This is really not a sensible thing to be doing in 2014 for anything other than extremely simple scripts: we have a proper technology for interfacing more complex applications with the web, and it's called WSGI. Use a micro-framework like Flask, and then you can much more simply achieve what you want: it would be easy to knock up an app in Flask that had your 2, 3 and 4 scripts simply as functions, and the original script dispatching to the relevant one. This makes much more sense because only one HTTP request is required, and it's all done in the same process.

Comment: Sigh. No, it wouldn't be "easy", and does not make "sense", because these endpoints are not all on the same site. One of the more annoying tendencies here is for "answerers" to assume they know the "why" of a question and go off on tangents. All I want to know is: Can I provoke the user's browser to make a POST request back to my server, rather than only a GET. **No, or yes with details.** I'm not interested in your new technology, I'm not interested in your opinion of my why's, your imagination of what my situation's limitations are, or aren't, or what you think I should be asking myself. +:

Comment: There *are* limitations. For one thing, altering very large projects takes time and money; to make the alterations possible, one doesn't simply switch technologies, OS, in midstream. I'm doing one small thing here, and I'm doing it in the context of what already works and exists. If I have to, I'll put the parameters in as a URL-appended query string and call it a day. It just didn't seem obvious to me that I should have to do that. So I asked. I do understand, as in your para 2, how to use URLLIB (or directly) to *originate* a request. That's why I'm not using it here. Not what I want to do.

Comment: One last thing: There are several ways the capability to pass parameters back to re-emit via a POST request could have been trivially implemented.  They could have been put in headers. They could have been flagged right in the "Location:" string with a double ?? instead of a single. Or, if the server POSTed *back to the caller* with a "Location:" header, it seems pretty obvious what is desired - and there's both the thing to do (forward, to location) and how to set up the environment. Any of those would suffice to tell the browser what it was being asked to do. Not unreasonable. Just webfail.

Comment: If the browser is to provoke what amounts to an indirect POST-to-own-CGI at the destination server, it has to pass the information back to the server somehow, just as it has to when it provides that URL?parm=value string. My suspicion that this might be possible stems from three things. First, that so many odd things are possible with HTTP; second that many of them are uncommonly used, or used in a very limited manner. The third is the simple obvious usefulness of not putting parameters where they can be trivially edited and seen by anyone, anytime. So forgive me, please. Hope springs eternal.